# IntelliJ doesn't show code comparison when selecting Resolve conflicts

Tags: intellij-idea, comparison, git-merge-conflict

I tried to rebase from my 'develop' branch (name of my main branch) and I have some conflicts. But I only get this dialog:

[image]

On a colleague's laptop if I double or triple click on the file it opens the window comparison where I can choose the code I would like to keep. But I can't seem to find how I can get that to open. I can only seem to be able to click 'Accept yours' or 'Accept theirs'. Has anyone faced this issue before?

I looked on Stackoverflow but couldn't find anything related to this.
I use the latest Intellij on MacOS Ventura

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it by accident, turns out I need to click on the green '+' button of the dialog window to zoom or expand the content of the conflict..